# How is this script (open-switch/opx-build/scripts/opx_run) passing variables?

Tags: bash, shell-script, docker

Like many bash questions, I'm 100% sure there is an answer but Googling them is challenging.

I'm trying to understand the following [script](https://github.com/open-switch/opx-build/blob/master/scripts/opx_run):

```
#!/bin/bash

# available options
export OPX_GIT_TAG="${OPX_GIT_TAG:-no}"

# package distribution
export OPX_RELEASE="${OPX_RELEASE:-unstable}"
# currently tracked release
export DIST="${DIST:-stretch}"
export ARCH="${ARCH:-amd64}"

export CUSTOM_SOURCES="${CUSTOM_SOURCES:-}"

# docker image name
IMAGE="opxhub/build"
# docker image tag
VERSION="${VERSION:-latest}"

interactive="-i"
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  # STDOUT is attached to TTY
  interactive="-it"
fi

read -d '' opx_docker_command <<- EOF
docker run
  --rm
  --name ${USER}_$(basename $PWD)_$$
  --privileged
  -e LOCAL_UID=$(id -u ${USER})
  -e LOCAL_GID=$(id -g ${USER})
  -v ${PWD}:/mnt
  -v $HOME/.gitconfig:/home/opx/.gitconfig
  -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  -e ARCH
  -e DIST
  -e OPX_RELEASE
  -e OPX_GIT_TAG
  -e CUSTOM_SOURCES
  ${interactive}
  ${IMAGE}:${VERSION}
EOF

if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
  # run command directly
  # not using bash because tar fails to complete
  # root cause unknown (see opx_rel_pkgasm.py:tar_in)
  $opx_docker_command sh -l -c "$*"
else
  # launch interactive shell
  # using bash here because tar does not fail in an interactive shell
  $opx_docker_command bash -l
fi
```

I'm confused by how they are generating their `docker-run` command - the parts about `ARCH`, `DIST`, `OPX_RELEASE`, etc - specifically. Should those not be enclosed with `${}`? If not how are these variables being passed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look carefully, you will see that the use of these variables is in a `-e` option of the `docker-run` command. This option is used to make environment variables available to the container.

So here, the script is specifying the *name* of the environment variable that should be passed to the container, and not the value itself (for which, as you stated correctly, it would have needed dereferencing, as in `$ARCH` or `${ARCH}`).

You can have a look at the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) for further reading.

Comment: Ohhh yeah - I forgot the syntax on how docker did environment variable passing. I confused it - that clears it up.

Comment: This isn't in the original question, but the other thing that has me confused is the `if [ -t 1 ]; then` bit - I understand that it has something to do with file descriptors, but it isn't clear to me exactly what that is?

Comment: That test checks if `stdin` (`-t 0`) or `stdout` (`-t 1`) of the script is a terminal.